# Folder delete error - can't delete folders extracted from zip

Tags: php, zip, extract, unlink, delete-directory

I'm having an issue deleting a directory in the server after it was extracted.

I've uploaded file.zip to the server, then created a file called "**en**", gave it permission **777** then extracted the content of file.zip to "**en**" and it was ok. 
The thing is, **I cannot now delete any file under** "**en**" however, renaming seems to work fine. I was able to rename "en" to "delete_me" and was able to rename
it's sub dir as well.

If I try to delete a single file under "delete_me" for example index.html, I get

```
Command:    DELE index.html
Response:   550 index.html: Permission denied
```

### 1- FTP delete attempt:

When I try to delete "delete_me" via FTP - FileZilla, it starts looping inside the dir and showing this message for each file:

```
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD
Response:   226 Transfer complete
Status: Directory listing successful
Command:    DELE index.html
Response:   550 index.html: Permission denied
Command:    CWD /httpdocs/_delete_me
Response:   250 CWD command successful
```

When I checked the (owner/group), I found it's (48/48) while other dir or files created by me have (10618/2524).

### 2- cPanel delete attempt:

I tried the to access via the hosting control panel File Manager then found the (**User/Group**) for folders inside "delete_me" is (**apache/apache** while for my files (**/psacln**)

When I try to delete the file from the hosting control panel, I get

```
Error: Unable to remove file /httpdocs/_delete_me// var/www/vhosts/<hostname>/httpdocs/_delete_me/tmp: filemng failed: rm: cannot remove `/var/www/vhosts/<hostname>/httpdocs/_delete_me/tmp/index.html': Permission denied
filemng: Error occured during /bin/rm command.
```

### 3- PHP Delete:

Last thing I tried to change permission `@chmod($dirPath, 0777);` and delete `rmdir($dirPath);`  or  `unlink($file);` but without a result.

The only resource found similar to my issue is here ([Forum Question](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?620228-PHP-unlink-error-can-t-delete-folder-extracted-from-zip)) but it seems it wasn't answered (*answer link provided is no longer available*).

**So, how to delete the file? **

Comment: Only empty directories can be deleted. You need first to delete all the contents.

Comment: same thing, cannot delete individual files such as index.html

Comment: that's because of permissions =)

Comment: FileZilla told me (Permission denied). Any work around this?

Comment: The php user is the same as Apache... the folder you upload to has the right chmod? tryed deathbypenguin2 solution?

Comment: (The php user is the same as Apache) this is good info. But why can't the php script change the permission? How to make it work?

Comment: because maybe it's not the owner of the folder or the file

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to chmod everything in that directory.

try this

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pathname));

$filemode = "0777"; // Set the permission

// Foreach item found set the permissions
foreach($iterator as $item) {
    chmod($item, $filemode);
}
```

if you're going to do `rmdir($dirPath);` be sure to remove all of the files from the directory first, otherwise I believe it will fail to remove the directory.

And of course to remove files using `unlink($filepath);` will work once the permissions have been set to the correct ones.

Comment: +1 for recursive but please add the fact that to can delete a folder you need before to not have file inside it ;)

Comment: I created a file called delete.php and used the code you provided. I got the following error:
(**Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/<domain>/httpdocs/delete.php on line 17**)

delete.php already has a *777*

Comment: That would be your PHP not having the permission to use chmod. Which may be your problem here. Check the ownership of the folders. Check what user is running apache, nginx or php. You'll need to add the user running your server to the group that owns the folders.

Comment: if available to you use `$this_user = posix_geteuid();` to get user running PHP. Then `posix_getpwuid($this_user);` will return an array of information including the username running PHP.